# 500 Custom Error Pages

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

I want to implement 500 error page for multi-sites/multi-languages, i am following [this article](https://sitecorecommerce.wordpress.com/2015/10/15/500-error-page-in-your-sitecore-application/).

But `Application_Error` in Global.asax is not firing. Here is my code:

```csharp
<%@ Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorApplication" %>
<script RunAt="server">

    private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var customErrorsSection = (System.Web.Configuration.CustomErrorsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
        var lastException = Server.GetLastError();
        if (customErrorsSection.Mode != System.Web.Configuration.CustomErrorsMode.Off)
        {
            try
            {
                // Log.Error( "There was an error in the application", lastException);
                Server.ClearError();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                Server.Transfer(string.Format("/Error/{0}_500.html", GetSafeLanguage()));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetSafeLanguage()
    {
        try
        {
            return Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I can see these potential problems: 1) `RunAt` should be spelled as `runat`; 2) Make sure that the class `WindsorApplication` inherits from `System.Web.HttpApplication`; 3) Try putting your methods into the class that you have in Global.asax.cs instead of having them inside `<script>` in Global.asax.

Comment: Ayman, have you tried the solutions from my previous comment?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I am using SOLR in my application and it needs this "WindsorApplication " to be on the global file and this class not inherited from "System.Web.HttpApplication", so what i am doing now is creating custom http handler to handle the error.

Comment: So you took another approach to your problem and this question should be closed then?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I am still trying to fix it using http handler approach, once it fixed we can close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am using SOLR, It needs WindsorApplication in Global.asax and this class not inherited from System.Web.HttpApplication, i follow these links to handle 500 page error :

https://sitecorecommerce.wordpress.com/2015/10/15/500-error-page-in-your-sitecore-application/

http://www.partechit.nl/en/blog/2014/01/sitecore-mvc-applications-and-the-application-error-event

**Connfiguation :**

```
<pipelines>
          <mvc.exception>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage, Sitecore.Mvc">
              <patch:attribute name="type">MyWebsite.Web.Pipelines.HandleMvcException, MyWebsite.Web</patch:attribute>
            </processor>
          </mvc.exception>
        </pipelines>
```

**My Class**

```
public class HandleMvcException : ExceptionProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(ExceptionArgs args)
        {
            var customErrorsSection = (CustomErrorsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
            var context = args.ExceptionContext;
            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
            var exception = context.Exception;

            if (customErrorsSection.Mode != CustomErrorsMode.Off)
            {
                if (context.ExceptionHandled || httpContext == null || exception == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                // Create a report with exception details.
                string exceptionInfo = this.GetExceptionInfo(httpContext, exception);
                // Store the report in a session variable so we can access it from the custom error page.
                Log.Error(string.Format("There was an error in {0} : {1}", Sitecore.Context.Site.Name, exceptionInfo),this);
                // Return a 500 status code and execute the custom error page.
                httpContext.Server.ClearError();
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                httpContext.Server.Execute((Sitecore.Context.Site.ErrorPage(GetSafeLanguage())));
            }
        }
        private string GetExceptionInfo(HttpContextBase httpContext, Exception exception)
        {
            // Generate an error report.
            var errorInfo = new StringBuilder();
            errorInfo.AppendLine(string.Concat("URL: ", httpContext.Request.Url));
            /* Snipped additional lines of report generation */
            errorInfo.AppendLine(string.Concat("Source: ", exception.Source));
            errorInfo.AppendLine(string.Concat("Message: ", exception.Message));
            errorInfo.AppendLine(string.Concat("Stacktrace: ", exception.StackTrace));

            return errorInfo.ToString();
        }
        private string GetSafeLanguage()
        {
            try
            {
                return Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

and in site definition i added custom attribute for error page :

```
  <site name="mywebsite" patch:before="site[@name='website']" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
            hostName ="mywebsite.local"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/mywebsite"
            startItem="/home"
            database="web"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="50MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false" 
            errorPage="/assets/error/mywebsite/{0}_500.html"/>
```

and I created extended method to read the errorPage attribute :

```
  public static class SiteExtension
    {
        /// <summary>  
        /// Retrun the site unique ID  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <returns></returns>  
        public static string ErrorPage(this SiteContext site, string language)
        {

            try
            {
                string errorPage = site.Properties["errorPage"];
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorPage))
                    return string.Format(errorPage, language);
                else
                    return string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```